# Сравнение с null в зависимости от апострофа дает разные результаты

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Есть таблица:

```
domain_registrations    
id | attached_to_hoster    
1  | null   
2  | null
```

Запросы:

```
select * from `domain_registrations` where 'attached_to_hoster' != 1;  
select * from `domain_registrations` where `attached_to_hoster` <> 1;
```

Первый - `attached_to_hoster` в обычных одинарных кавычках.
Второй - `attached_to_hoster` в грависах.

Результат - обе строки в первом случае, ни одной во втором.
Ситуация усугубляется тем, что запрос конструируется в `laravel`.

```
$oDomainRegistrations = DomainRegistrations::where('attached_to_hoster', '<>', '1')->get();
```

Как добиться чтобы возвращалась адекватная выборка?

Comment: Спасибо за форматирование.

Comment: То, что у вас одиночные кавычки "'" вместо апострофов "`" - точно не играет роли? Просто вопрос не совсем понял. Вопрос про апострофы, а их в нем нет. Кстати, как заключить в комментарии одиночный апостроф в код?

Comment: *Результат - обе строки в первом случае* Что удивительного? Вы сравниваете строковый литерал с числом, ясен пень они не равны. *ни одной во втором* Если предположить, что символ `~` при передаче на MySQL заменяется на бэктик `\`` - то всё верно, ибо любое (кроме случая Null-safe compare `<=>`) сравнение с Null всегда даёт Null, который интерпретируется как False. Так что опять всё ровно. *Как добиться чтобы возвращалась адекватная выборка?* А какая именно для Вас - адекватная?

Comment: А в laravel можно задать отрицание условия. что бы запрос выглядел как `where NOT attached_to_hoster = 1` ?

Answer (score 0):

NULL это не определенность исходите из того, что в обоих случаях ваши проверки неизвестен. Это и не 1 и не "не 1". :) По этому делайте проверки на null например (в зависимости от того, надо вам в выборку такие записи или нет)

```
select * from domain_registrations 
 where attached_to_hoster != 1 and not attached_to_hoster is null;
select * from domain_registrations 
 where attached_to_hoster != 1 or attached_to_hoster is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если есть возможность редактирования столбцов таблицы `domain_registrations` - установите для столбца `attached_to_hoster` значение по умолчанию, равное 0, например. Это позволит избежать нюансов работы с null. И

```
DomainRegistrations::where('attached_to_hoster', '<>', '1')
```

будет работать корректно.